# How to Create a form in Django admin without creating a model

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I want to use the django admin template but want to create my form in django admin without using models. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: you can find the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148923/is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-admin-view-without-a-model-behind-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the admin template HTML and add whatever you want

You can find it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)